# Any change in orientation definition in iOS 6

Tags: ios, ios6, screen-orientation, uiinterfaceorientation

I have this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

in my app view controllers, in iOS 5 it worked as expected but when I updated to iOS 6, the orientation definition doesnt seem to work, it is also showing landscape when oriented. Any change in method definition of any other settings?

Comment: Are you testing on a device, the simulator for iOS 6 seems to have some problems with rotation and will only allow the new way of rotation.

Comment: ofcourse, there is new method added in iOS 6 for orientation. you can read documentation regarding same to more understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the `AppDelegate`:

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window  // iOS 6
{

return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;


}
```

in your ViewController:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Comment: As far as I recall, `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll` is not a `BOOL`.

Comment: Edited my answer, im doing alot of stuff in my code, so when i cut the other art of code, my answer appears to be wrong

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Jossef's answer and would add one thing.

I have an older iOS app that I've migrated up to iOS6. In my AppDelegate I originally added the main view controller like this:

```
 [self.window addSubview:videoController.view];
```

with that line, the new autoRotation selectors Jossef mentioned still don't work. You have to update the AppDelegate line to set your rootViewController like this:

```
 self.window.rootViewController = videoController;
```